# Rails Integration Test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, integration-testing

I am taking a Rails class and am stuck on an Integration test. I have made a simple app that a user can use to share a link to a website. I want to create a test that will:

1. Get the amount of links currently in the database
2. Post a new link
3. Check that the number of links has increased by 1.

Here is what I have so far:

```
test "posts new link and check count" do
   @link = Links.all
   get "/links/new"
   post_via_redirect "/links/new", :url => links(:test_link).url, :description => links(:test_link).description
   assert_equal '/links/new', path
   assert_difference("Link.count",n) do
```

I know this doesn't work but I cannot figure out the wording/syntax and would really appreciate a nod in the right direction. Please let me know if I should include other information.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#integration-testing should be useful.

Answer (score 3):

This is very simple. Assume you use the `minitest` for functional tests.

The test cases should be wrapped to something like `class MyLinksControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` where `MyLinksControllerTest` should have the same name like your actual controller.

> Get the amount of links currently in the database.

```
 test 'should get index page' do
    get :index
    assert_response :success
    refute assigns(:links).empty?
  end
```

`:get` the `:index` page and be sure what response is a `:success` or `:ok`. `refute` if `@links` variable a empty array(doesn't contain any link).

> Post a new link

```
  test "should get new page" do
    get :new
    assert_response :success
  end
```

Check `get` request of a `:new` action. (not sure about this action, but test it just for success response)

> Check that the number of links has increased by 1.

```
 test "post action should create a link and redirect" do
    assert_difference "Link.count", 1 do
      post :create, link_name: "some name", link: '/some_link_here'

      assert_response :redirect
    end
  end
```

`:post` to the `:create` action with some of `params` and be sure what  response is `:redirect` and `Link.count` increased by 1.

[`Happy testing!`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#integration-testing)

Comment: For the third test, should "some name" and '/some_link_here' be populated with the data I have set up in my fixture file?

Comment: @Steven from anywhere, it  just example for you how to make a functional test for your app.